# IIS7 Redirect pattern

Tags: redirect, iis-7, url-rewriting

Using IIS7 with rewrite module to create a redirect

Source request URL: http://www.domain.com/term/code.html?Product=55824
Should redirect to http://www.domain.com/product/55824

Current Rule (does not work)

```
<rule name="PatternRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="term/([a-z]+)(.*)Product=([0-9]+)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.domain.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/product/{R:3}"
            redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Any ideas why the above isnt working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query string is not included in main match string, you have to use Conditions to evaluate it.

```
<rule name="PatternRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^term/.*" />
          <conditions  trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="Product=([0-9]+)" />         
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domain.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/product/{C:1}"
            redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Remove `{HTTP_HOST}` condition. Does it redirect anywhere at all?